# Growing Line Android Effect

Tags: android, android-animation

I am developing an android app and I should draw a line from the Point A to the Point B but I would like to show this line be drawing  "progressively" from one point to other. How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First: Accept some answers on your previous questions. Thats how this community encourage people to answer your questions. Second: Provide more information about how you "draw". Do you use a SurfaceView? OpenGL-ES? Normal xml layout with which views? A good question is the basic for good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Thread` to progressively increase the size of your line, by increasing its ending `x` position, as an example, and then call `View.postInvalidate()` from your thread.

This way, if `x` is the ending of your line and `view` the `View` that draws a line ending at `x` you would have this thread:

```
class LineThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (x < some_limit) {
           x += some_value;
           view.postInvalidate();

           try {
               sleep(some_time);
           }
           catch(InterruptedException e) {
               log.e(getClass.getName(), "sleep() was interrupted", e);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

and in your `view`:

```
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawLine(left, top, right + x, bottom, paint);
}
```

Making `LineThread` a subclass of your `View` class would make it easy as they could share `x`.

Comment: Humm... There is no other easier way? Because in this way I should calculate all the points where my line pass on, and it is going to get complicated if I use inclined lines or simple curves.

Comment: Well, this is the way I would do. It's not complicated at all if the line is tilted. It's more complicated if this is a curve.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), but I'm not sure if it'll be too time consuming just for this - should be fine if you're only doing it for a few lines at a time!

Since you have the `start_point` and your `end_point`, you can lerp to find the `current_point` for each timeframe and then use `drawLine` between `start_point` and `current_point`.

Comment: @deniswsrosa don't forget to vote up/accept the useful answers ;)